# Captcha what Captcha

Tags: bug, status-planned, captcha

I'm assuming the captcha is initially triggered because I have an ad-blocker and presumably I'm also blocking the actual captcha box.

[image]

I'm blocking:

- google-analytics.com
- googletagservices.com
- secure.quantserve.com
- sb.scorecardresearch.com

But allowing:

- ajax.googleapis.com
- cdn.sstatic.net

Comment: Oh captcha, my captcha...

Comment: Maybe you're not enough human for the system.

Comment: @Maroun - I had hoped that if I was a replicant I would be stronger and better looking. Roy Batty I am not!

Comment: Real humans would try unblocking urls one by one to see if that solved there problem.

Comment: @HansPassant none of the blocked ones deserve unblocking. If I need to unblock some js for stackoverflow to work = ok. Unblocking some google tracking / datamining cookie so SO can sell info about me while I'm providing answers for free = no deal

Comment: Any error on the console?

Comment: Yeahhh that's broken two ways. For one, you *should* see an actual captcha there. That might be related to your blocks. For another, however, even if you did see it, we don't handle the response correctly there. I'll fix ASAP (or find someone else to).

Comment: @AdamLear - thanks, I assumed the hex string is a bug identifier, but I couldn't find any other way to submit it.

Comment: @MartinBeckett It’s not even that. :) It’s a GUID that’s supposed to identify your “session” on the backend, so that once captcha is validated, we know what request to get back to. This is where this whole thing gets funny. That pop up view assumes that its model is a string error message and renders it into the view. Bad copy/paste from the old version of the captcha controls, basically. I have it half-fixed, just need to get the session persistence/lookup to work correctly again.

Comment: When in doubt, click on anything that looks like a car or sign. Again and again.

Answer (score 9):

Answer is to disable captcha as it does nothing to prevent abuse as it is! More on this on the last paragraph.

I do not use ghostery and also get this silliness.

Since i log into this site every full moon or so, I always mistype my password a couple times, then when I do get the password right on the 3rd try, it asks me to fill in an invisible captcha! (uBlock-Origin, and block google tracking domains and IPs)

Now to add insult to injury, this is probably being done in malice (for better advertisement revenue?), or not in a very competent way for security. Because 1) it already confirmed i correctly typed in the password in the 3rd try; and 2) if i clear my cookies, i can try my password more than a dozen times and, having no prior cookies, not see the captcha request when i finally get the password right. heck I am typing this in a firefox Private window because i got the captcha on my main window and a private window was faster than clearing the cookies yet again. In Summary, it is annoying to fellow humans, and actual robots can just ignore the cookies and hammer passwords at will. Just turn it off unless you see a thousand password attempts from a single IP or something.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Ghostery, which blocks a lot of requests to tracking systems and others that tracks you. This is great for your privacy, but this add-on can lead to JavaScript errors in other parts of the page.

Ghostery actually doesn't block any requests to Google's captcha, but other requests that are being blocked may have caused a Javascript error that prevented it from loading. Either that, or you have other ad/tracking/javascript blocking add-on that is blocking the captcha. Try whitelisting tracking in Stack Overflow for a better experience.

Comment: Could you replicate this using just ghostery? Or is this just a guess?

Comment: Yes, it is replicable just by using Ghostery.